# Python dataframe dictionary aggregation merging with sum failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas, merge

Suppose I have such dataframe:

```
da1 = DataFrame({'id':['bub','char', 'bub'],
                 'a':[{'t1':1,'t2':3},
                      {'t1':3},
                      {'t2':1}]})
print da1
                      a    id
0  {u't2': 3, u't1': 1}   bub
1            {u't1': 3}  char
2            {u't2': 1}   bub
```

I want to sum the content of the column 'a' by key, grouping by 'id', what I tried was:

```
print da1.groupby('id')\
        .aggregate({
            'a': lambda x: DataFrame.from_dict(x).sum().to_dict()})
id                                                    a 
bub   <built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f...
char  <built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f...
```

But if I do the follow:

```
bub = [{'t1':1,'t2':3}, {'t2':1}]
print DataFrame.from_dict(bub).sum().to_dict()
{'t2': 4.0, 't1': 1.0}
```

I get what I wanted in the first time,
what am I missing?

upd: I also tried using the Counter(), with no success...

```
from collections import Counter
print dict(sum((Counter(dict(x)) for x in bub),Counter()))
{'t2': 4, 't1': 1}

print da1.groupby('id')\
            .aggregate({
                'a': lambda dic: dict(sum((Counter(dict(x)) for x in dic),Counter()))})
id                                                    a 
bub   <built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f...
char  <built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f...
```

Comment: I doubt if your first dataframe, da1, is what you want: a column with dicts for values is usually not something you'd put into a dataframe.

Comment: You are right! I will actually use a very similar structure to insert such field into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this, maybe very inefficient but it worked for me.

I found an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8735) about a similar error when using the apply method and that bug was fixed. Since they fixed for apply I used the apply function to do what I want.

```
print DataFrame({'visitorId':da1.groupby('id', as_index=False).groups.keys(),
           'a':da1.groupby('id', as_index=False)\
                        .apply(lambda dic:
                                dict(sum((Counter(dict(x)) for x in dic.a),
                                          Counter())))})

                      a visitorId
0  {u't2': 4, u't1': 1}       bub
1            {u't1': 3}      char
```

I used the apply method on the grouped data, and the easiest way to get the 'identifier' was to get the groups keys. If you have a suggestion on how to do this more efficiently let me know!